# The requested URL could not be matched by routing. ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

This is the error that i am getting. I am learning zf2 from a book but they forget to say where i should put this piece of code (i tried few attempts but none of them wokred.)
This is my module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Index' =>
                'Users\Controller\IndexController',
            'Users\Controller\Register' =>
                'Users\Controller\RegisterController',
            'Users\Controller\Login' =>
                'Users\Controller\LoginController',
            'Users\Controller\UserManager' =>
                'Users\Controller\UserManagerController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/users',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' =>
                                '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' =>
                                    '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' =>
                                    '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Where should this be ?

```
'user-manager' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/User-manager[/:action[/:id]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Users\Controller\UserManager',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

The url is

```
http://zend2.com/users/user-manager/edit/5
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the `'child_routes'` array instead of the default route. which should depending if you want to use it should be on the same level as `'users'`

Also in the route the address is written with a uppercase U in User-manager this is case sensative so you should write ur address as `http://zend2.com/users/User-manager/edit/5`

Comment: Thank you ! I tried to place it under child_routes but it wasnt working , but i didn't notice the U. Now its working.